# What does FC mean?

Tags: nodeos, compilation, error

When I see EOSIO log errors, there are many things that start with FC. By the way, what exactly does prefix "FC" mean here?

```
ex)
FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( chain_type_exception, chain_exception,
                                  3010000, "chain type exception" )
FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( name_type_exception,               chain_type_exception,
                                    3010001, "Invalid name" )
      FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( public_key_type_exception,         chain_type_exception,
                                    3010002, "Invalid public key" )
      FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( private_key_type_exception,        chain_type_exception,
                                    3010003, "Invalid private key" )
      FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( authority_type_exception,          chain_type_exception,
                                    3010004, "Invalid authority" )
      FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( action_type_exception,             chain_type_exception,
                                    3010005, "Invalid action" )
      FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( transaction_type_exception,        chain_type_exception,
                                    3010006, "Invalid transaction" )
      FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( abi_type_exception,                chain_type_exception,
                                    3010007, "Invalid ABI" )
      FC_DECLARE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION( block_id_type_exception,           chain_type_exception,
                                    3010008, "Invalid block ID" )
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Quick answer to your question:*

From [bytemasters fc-repo](https://github.com/bytemaster/fc)

> FC stands for fast-compiling c++ library ...

*Additional Info for others reading this:*

The [mandel-fc-repo](https://github.com/eosnetworkfoundation/mandel-fc) contains a lot of these FC_XXX macros for things like Exceptions, Reflection, Logging and more, basically these macro-usages are replaced with compileable code at compilation-time.

The macros from your example are replaced with individual classes for each exception like you can see here: [fc/exception/exception.hpp](https://github.com/eosnetworkfoundation/mandel-fc/blob/863dc8d371fd4da25f89cb08b13737f009a9cec7/include/fc/exception/exception.hpp#L259)